# Matrix dimensions do not agree when plotting a formula in Matlab

Tags: matlab, operators, vectorization

I am trying to plot satellite orbits in matlab. This is the question and formula:
[image: This is the question and formula]

This is my code so far.

```
clear;
clc;

a = linspace(0,2 .* pi,360);
p = 1000;
e1 = ([0 .25 .50]);

r1 = (p) ./ (1 - (e1 .* (cos(a))));
```

It produces this error:

> Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> ```
> Error in hw5 (line 8)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.*`, `./` or `.^`, both sides must have same sizes. In your code `e1` and `cos(a)` are not of same sizes. If you want to calculate distance of satellite for different eccentricities, you can use a for loop:

```
clear; clc; close all;

a = linspace(0,2 .* pi,360);
p = 1000;
e1 = [0 .25 .50];

for e=e1
    r1 = (p) ./ (1 - (e .* cos(a)));
    polarplot(a, r1), hold on
end
```

You also can use [bsxfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) if you want to do it without using loops:

```
clear; clc; close all;

a = linspace(0,2 .* pi,360);
p = 1000;
e1 = [0 .25 .50];
denominator = bsxfun(@(e, a) 1 - (e .* cos(a)), e1', a);
r1 = bsxfun(@rdivide, p, denominator);
polarplot(repmat(a', 1, 3), r1')
```

Comment: How would I plot using a polar plot

Comment: @MuazSadique edited my answer, now it plots using `polarplot`.